# Basic python questino about import

Tags: python, import, pip

I am trying to run some Python (2.7.6) code, and the compiler can't find the "util" module.

Here is the line from the code:
    *from util import getArgs, write*

And the error is this:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rs.py", line 11, in 
    from util import getArgs, write
ImportError: No module named util*

I can't find this util module anywhere, and pip install does not recognize util, getArgs, and write. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-utils/1.5.2
might help you

Comment: There is not `util` module. Are you thinking of `utils`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments have pointed out, it should be **utils** (plural) and *not* **util**

```
from utils import <your package>
```